# Validation of Comma Separated Email in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to Validate the list of Email which is comma Separated in Scala.

```
For Ex:1) a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com,c@gmail.com ---Valid
       2) a@gmail.com,b@@gmail.com,c@gmail.com---Invalid
       3) a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com.c@gmail.com----Invalid
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If your question has been correctly answered, consider marking the answer as accepted (like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png)) so that it can help future people that come across the same issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what "invalid" means, this could work:

```scala
def isValid(emails: String): Boolean = {
  return emails.split(",").map(_.count(_ == '@') == 1).reduce(_ && _)
}

isValid("a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com,c@gmail.com")  // true
isValid("a@gmail.com,b@@gmail.com,c@gmail.com")  // false
isValid("a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com.c@gmail.com")  // false
```

I'm just splitting the string by commas, then I check that there is only one `@` in it.

If you really want to check that the email is correct, you can use a regex like this:

```scala
def isValid(emails: String): Boolean = {
  return emails.split(",").map(_.matches(raw"[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}")).reduce(_ && _)
}
```

This is probably better, but it is not specific enough to capture all email specificities. Matching all types of emails is not something easy to do with regex (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)).

Comment: Thank you very much, Its working as expected

Comment: I added a few details if you want to have a look. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if this solution worked for you